# Почему при билде добавляется <script defer='defer'> вместо простого <script>

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, npm

Исходный код:

```js
function component() {
    const element = document.createElement('div');

    // Lodash, currently included via a script, is required for this line to work
    element.innerHTML = 'Hello Webpack';

    return element;
}

document.body.appendChild(component());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="class">Hi world</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>GS_1C</title><script defer="defer" src="main.js"></script></head><body><div class="class">Hi urod</div></body></html>
```

package.json

```
  "name": "GS_1C",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "project who must help to calculate subscription fee",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": ""
  },
  "homepage": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.0",
    "webpack": "^5.22.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'main.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
            title: "GS_1C",
            template: "./index.html"
        })
    ]
};
```

подскажите, почему у меня при билде проекта на выходе скрипт выходит как `defer="defer"`?

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/html/script/defer

Comment: @gil9red Спасибо за ответ, но вы не поняли вопроса. что такое defer я знаю. Я не понимаю, почему defer добавился при сборке вебпаком?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По умолчанию `HTMLWebpackPlugin` делает [оптимизации](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#options). Если хотите выключить это поведение, то добавьте параметр `scriptLoading`:

```
plugins: [
    new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
        title: "GS_1C",
        template: "./index.html",
        scriptLoading: "blocking"
    })
]
```